# Inside a structure how can I define an array (dynamic) of structures with the same type as the structure itself

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, structure

The objective is to build a "infinite" tree using dynamic arrays.

```
items[3]
- MENUITEM
  - items[2]
    - MENUITEM
      -items[0]
    - MENUITEM
      - items[0]
- MENUITEM
  - items[0]
- MENUITEM
  - items[2]
    - MENUITEM
      - items[0]
    - MENUITEM
      - items[0]
```

I define the structure:

```
typedef struct MENUITEM {
    char id, count;
    char *description;
};
```

And I can allocated items dynamically with:

```
char count;
MENUITEM items[], *items_ptr;

count++;
realloc( items_ptr, count * sizeof(struct MENUITEM) );
```

The problem is that inside the structure I cannot assign again the structure itself like:

```
typedef struct MENUITEM {
    char id, count;
    char *description;

    MENUITEM items[], *items_ptr;
};
```

The compiler outputs: error: field ‘items’ has incomplete type; what am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `struct MENUITEM *items_ptr;`.  Note the use of the word `struct`.

Why do you have `MENUITEM items[]`?  It's not used for anything.

Do this instead:

```
typedef struct MENUITEM {
    char id, count;
    char *description;

    struct MENUITEM *items;
} MENUITEM;

void foo() {
    MENUITEM *root = (MENUITEM*)malloc(sizeof(MENUITEM));

    root->id = 87;
    root->count = 5;

    root->items = (MENUITEM*)malloc(sizeof(MENUITEM)*root->count);
}
```

Comment: items[] is used further ahead on the code like (after the realloc):
items[ this->count -1 ].id = 1337;
items[ this->count -1 ].description = "Some stuff";

Comment: Thanks ! I was accessing the childs like: "items[ parent_id ].items[ count -1 ].id = id;", how should them be accessed now ?

Comment: @Joao: Use `items[x]->items[y]->items[z]->id`.

Comment: This means that every item is a pointer to another MENUITEM struct ?

Comment: @Joao: Oops, sorry, it's still `items[x].items[y].items[z].id`.  I didn't think that through very well before typing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the MenuItem structure to hold a pointer to `MENUITEM`

```
typedef struct MENUITEM {
    char id, count;
    char *description;

    MENUITEM *items_ptr;
};
```

Not alone that the allocation is not good either - it would be much slower doing this

```
count++;
realloc( items_ptr, count * sizeof(struct MENUITEM) );
```

You would be better off allocating a block of memory say to hold 50 entries, when the limit has reached, `realloc` it with twice the block size and please ensure that you do not clobber the result like this:

Correct:

```
MENUITEM *temp_items_ptr;
temp_items_ptr = realloc( items_ptr, count * sizeof(struct MENUITEM) );
if (temp_items_ptr != NULL){
   items_ptr = temp_items_ptr;
}else{
   /* Handle the out of memory situtation */
}
```

Wrong:

```
items_ptr = realloc( items_ptr, count * sizeof(struct MENUITEM) );
```

The wrong approach is a recipe for disaster and say hello to leaked memory!

Comment: I consider your advice a wise one but on the context where this code will be run, running out of memory is very easy (Arduino development board).